# New path for new installation of omnet in linux

Tags: linux, omnet++, reinstall

There is a problem with `PATH` variable. Though I added the path to omnet folder I face this error:

```
ERROR: /home/user/omnetpp-4.2.1/bin is not in the path! You can add it by entering:
   export PATH=/home/user/omnetpp-4.2.1/bin:$PATH
```

I installed omnet++ 5.0, set the `PATH` variable and it worked well. Then I needed to install omnet++ 4.2.1. So I added this folder to home, changed the variables `PATH` and `OMNET_DIR` from the omnetpp-5.0 (previously working fine omnet) to omnetpp-4.2 (the new one) in the bashrc file.

Then typed `sourc ~/.bashrc` and tried the new variables by the instructions `echo $PATH` and `echo $OMNET_DIR`.

So far, everything is fine. And the variables are set to the new omnetpp-4.2 .1 folder.

Then I run `./configure` in the omnetpp-4.2.1 folder and I face the error mentioned above, While the path is set correctly!

How can I fix it?

tnx

Comment: If you open a new terminal and you type 'echo $PATH' does the output contain the path of your OMNeT++ download?

Comment: @thardes2 yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use two or more different versions of OMNeT++ on the same machine, the best way to do it is to remove EVRYTHING OMNeT++ related from the  .bashrc and similar startup scripts and then logout/login.

Now whenever you want to work with a particular OMNeT++ version, open a terminal and go to the root of the particular OMNeT++ install. Source the setenv script there:

```
$ . setenv
```

And do everything omnet++ related in that terminal. 
You can even open an other terminal with the other OMNeT++ version the same way and use both of them in parallel. (you should also start the IDE from the terminal using the `omnetpp` command)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I should add that I installed omnet++ 5.3. Then tried to see I can switch to another version and I successfully switched to omnet++ 5.3. But then I couldn't launch the other two earlier versions. I also deleted omnet path from bashrch,logged in again and tried . setenv in omnet++ 4.2.1 folder it printed the current path. Then I typed `omnetpp` in the terminal but there was an error `command not found`. The same happened when I tried it in the omnet++ 5.0 folder.Then I tried it in omnet++ 5.3 folder and it worked. To sum, it just works for the latest version installed.

Comment: No. As there is nothing OMNeT++ related in in your startup scripts the computer cannot know which version we *last* installed. What you are probably missing is that each and every version MUST be properly installed (i.e. run the . setenv, then ./configure and finally make). Without that, the given version will obviously not work.

Comment: Yes, u're right. It worked. But v.4.2.1 still has a problem. When I `make` it an error shows up: `abspath.cc:62:38: error: ‘getcwd’ was not declared in this scope
     return std::string(getcwd(wd,1024)) + "/" + pathname; //XXX results in doub
                                      ^
Makefile:59: recipe for target '/home/user/omnetpp-4.2.1/out/gcc-release/src/utils/abspath' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/omnetpp-4.2.1/out/gcc-release/src/utils/abspath] Error 1`